# Google Sheets script, copyto and replace existing sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been searching for the past few weeks and haven't been able to figure out this script. What I'm trying to do is figure out a way for me to duplicate a pictorial calendar on a master Google Sheets file to another Google Sheets file that I manage. Every time there's an update on the master calendar, I'd love for it to automatically update in the other Google Sheets file that I manage. Right now I have to copy paste everything, reformat, and reimport images. I did find a script that somewhat works, but it has some issues that cause it to be just as much work.

The script is a copyTo script, it allows me to copy a sheet titled "Pictorial Calendar" from the master Google Sheets file (called "Master Calendar") to a different Google Sheets file (called "My Calendar"). I even set up a trigger that allows the script to run whenever I make an edit.

However, it keeps creating new sheets titled "Copy of Pictorial Calendar 1" "Copy of Pictorial Calendar 2" etc.) and I can't figure out how to make the script replace the existing sheet instead of creating new sheets.

I also would love to be able to change the duplicated sheet to just be called "Pictorial Calendar" in the "My Calendar" file. The script I'm using is:

```
function copyMasterCalendar() {
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = source.getSheets()[2];

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1exiUWVypFpYeHMkXHO3sMUTGupiC2gQjZIF0Ss44-pU");

 sheet.copyTo(destination);
}
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try this...

```
function copyMasterCalendar() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = source.getSheetByName('Pictorial Calendar'),
      destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1exiUWVypFpYeHMkXHO3sMUTGupiC2gQjZIF0Ss44-pU"),
      destSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Pictorial Calendar'),
      copydSheet = sheet.copyTo(destination);
  copydSheet.getDataRange().copyTo(destSheet.getDataRange());
  destination.deleteSheet(copydSheet);
}
```

Comment: I think you understood me correctly, that script works almost correctly. It doesn't import the formatting or the images that are on the original sheet (the copyTo script I initially listed does). I spent several hours trying to figure it out but haven't been successful. Is it possible to also import formatting and images? I really like how your script does not create duplicate sheets but overwrites the existing one.

Comment: How about changing deleting the last two lines to...`destination.deleteSheet(destSheet);` & `copydSheet.setName('Pictorial Calendar');`.  Basically delete the original sheet and rename the copy.

Comment: Thank you so much! That last edit makes the script run flawlessly now, this is amazing! You really helped me with saving time and many headaches, thanks again @mongoose36!

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help.